# Duda sobre Boxing y Unboxing en Java

Tags: java

he estado practicando el tema de Boxing y Autoboxing en Java y me ha surgido una duda. Se que cada tipo de dato primitivo tiene su clase "Wrapper" para ser tratado como objeto. Pero específicamente en el siguiente código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer a = 1;
    Double b = 2.0;

    System.out.println(a.equals(1) ? a : b);
}
```

La salida en pantalla me da 1.0.
¿Porqué imprime 1.0 como Double si está declarado a como Integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### En estos casos conviene comprobar la [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/index.html) o JLS

Específicamente en el punto [15.25.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.2) se habla sobre el operador ternario que estás usando y que, efectivamente, es la causa de tu problema:

> Las expresiones condicionales numéricas son expresiones únicas.
>
> El tipo de una expresión condicional numérica se determina de la siguiente manera:
>
> Si el segundo y tercer operandos tienen el mismo tipo, entonces ese es el tipo de la expresión.
>
> Si uno de los dos últimos operandos es un primitivo de tipo `T`, y el otro es el resultado de aplicar *boxing* a `T`, entonces el tipo es `T`.
>
> `[...]`
>
> De cualquier otra manera, se aplica la [promoción binaria numérica](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) a los tipos de los operandos, y **el tipo de la expresión es el tipo promocionado de `[o bien]` el segundo `[o bien]`  el tercer operando**.

**(Traducido y resaltado por mi)**

Es este último punto el que nos interesa. En este caso, se está aplicando la promoción numérica, por la cual Java intenta acomodar el tipo más restrictivo (en este caso `Integer`) al menos restrictivo (en este caso `Double`)

Comment: buena solucion me gusto bastante tu explicacion.

Answer (score 1):

El problema no está relacionado con el boxing o unboxing. Lo que ocurre es que el operador ternario (?:) tiene un comportamiento un tanto peculiar. Por ejemplo, en el siguiente código:

```
a.equals(1) ? a : b
```

`a.equals(1)` se corresponde con la expresión condicional la cual determina que varores (en este caso `a` o `b`) se "retornará" como resultado. Si la expresión a la izquierda del `?` se evalúa como `true` entonces se retornará el valor resultante de evaluar la expresión a la izquierda de los dos puntos (:); y en caso de evaluarse como `false` se retorna el valor resultante de evaluar la expresión a la derecha de los dos puntos. Ahora bien, se recomienda que los tipos de dato que retorna la evaluación de las expresiones a la izquierda y derecha de los dos puntos sean iguales, para evitar errores y/o comportamientos extraños como en este caso.

Que te está ocurriendo, que `a` es de tipo `Integer` y `b` de tipo `Double`, por lo que el compilador determina que el tipo de dato que retorna como resultado de la sentencia `a.equals(1) ? a : b` será `Double`, ya que no puede convertir un `Double` en `Integer` porque se perderían datos (en primera porque se pierde la parte decimal), pero por el contrario si puede convertir un `Integer` a `Double` sin que se pierdan datos.

Por todo lo anterior te reitero la recomendación: "procura que las expresiones a la izquierda y a la derecha de los dos puntos (:) se evalúen al mismo tipo de dato".